# jPicker - broken images

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, jquery-plugins

I'm using Django and jquery, implementing jPicker http://www.digitalmagicpro.com/jPicker/ in my web application. Here I'm getting broken images on jPicker color display. When I check the server code it shows like this

```
"GET /files/css/jPicker-1.1.6.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
"GET /files/css/jPicker.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
"GET /files/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
"GET /files/js/jpicker-1.1.6.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
"GET /jPicker/images/mappoint.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 3209
"GET /jPicker/images/rangearrows.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 3218
"GET /jPicker/images/Maps.png HTTP/1.1" 404 3197
"GET /jPicker/images/map-opacity.png HTTP/1.1" 404 3218
"GET /jPicker/images/Bars.png HTTP/1.1" 404 3197
"GET /jPicker/images/bar-opacity.png HTTP/1.1" 404 3218
"GET /jPicker/images/AlphaBar.png HTTP/1.1" 404 3209
"GET /jPicker/images/preview-opacity.png HTTP/1.1" 404 3230
"GET /jPicker/images/NoColor.png HTTP/1.1" 404 3206
```

The image files are not found there showing 404, but I linked the **images** folder inside the css folder correctly.

```
/home/nirmal/try/files/css/images/
/home/nirmal/try/files/css/jPicker.css
/home/nirmal/try/files/css/jPicker-1.1.6.min.css
/home/nirmal/try/files/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
/home/nirmal/try/files/js/jpicker-1.1.6.min.js
```

My Django settings are

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/nirmal/try/files/'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/files/'
```

What mistake I've done that makes the images to be on **jPicker/images** and not found?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jPicker has a default variable that states where the images folder is located:

```
 $.fn.jPicker.defaults = /* jPicker defaults - you can change anything in this section (such as the clientPath to your images) without fear of breaking the program */
 {
   images:
   {
      clientPath: '/jPicker/images/', /* Path to image files */
   }
 }
```

You should overwrite this default to `images.clientPath = '/files/css/images/'`, for instance like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
  $(document).ready(
    function()
    {
      $('#your-element').jPicker({images:{clientPath: '/files/css/images/'}});
    });
</script>
```

See also the section 'Settings' at http://www.digitalmagicpro.com/jPicker/  (to bad I can not link the exact location, but Ctrl + F is your friend).

good luck,
Wout